# WPF PrintVisual on receipt printer is clipping image

Tags: c#, wpf, printing

I'm printing a visual in WPF to a receipt printer (Star TSP 700II).
When the visual is small it is fine and it prints okay.

However when the visual grows it will clip the image and it prints to a certain size on the roll in the Star printer and then it just cuts without printing the remainder of the image.

```
PrintDialog.PrintVisual(Grid1, "Test");
```

I've tried adjusting the PageMediaSize but that is not changing anything on the printout.

Interesting when I print to Microsoft XPS Document Writer the saved file has the full image.

[image]

I've also noticed the size it prints to is always maximum height = height of an A4 page.
Question is how to I get it to print past the height of an A4 (when I print a test document from the printer preferences it is able to do this).

Comment: Your barcode is completely readable.

Comment: Its only off a test server anyway, so doesn't really matter (thanks for the heads up though).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok I solved this using following class. Basically I put what I want to print inside a scrollviewer and put a stackpanel inside that, then pass this stackpanel to my print helper and it now prints without clipping:

```
public static class PrintHelper
{

    public static FixedDocument GetFixedDocument(FrameworkElement toPrint, PrintDialog printDialog)
    {
        var capabilities = printDialog.PrintQueue.GetPrintCapabilities(printDialog.PrintTicket);
        var pageSize = new Size(printDialog.PrintableAreaWidth, printDialog.PrintableAreaHeight);
        var visibleSize = new Size(capabilities.PageImageableArea.ExtentWidth, capabilities.PageImageableArea.ExtentHeight);
        var fixedDoc = new FixedDocument();
        //If the toPrint visual is not displayed on screen we neeed to measure and arrange it  
        toPrint.Measure(new Size(double.PositiveInfinity, double.PositiveInfinity));
        toPrint.Arrange(new Rect(new Point(0, 0), toPrint.DesiredSize));
        //  
        var size = toPrint.DesiredSize;
        //Will assume for simplicity the control fits horizontally on the page  
        double yOffset = 0;
        while (yOffset < size.Height)
        {
            var vb = new VisualBrush(toPrint)
            {
                Stretch = Stretch.None,
                AlignmentX = AlignmentX.Left,
                AlignmentY = AlignmentY.Top,
                ViewboxUnits = BrushMappingMode.Absolute,
                TileMode = TileMode.None,
                Viewbox = new Rect(0, yOffset, visibleSize.Width, visibleSize.Height)
            };
            var pageContent = new PageContent();
            var page = new FixedPage();
            ((IAddChild)pageContent).AddChild(page);
            fixedDoc.Pages.Add(pageContent);
            page.Width = pageSize.Width;
            page.Height = pageSize.Height;
            var canvas = new Canvas();
            FixedPage.SetLeft(canvas, capabilities.PageImageableArea.OriginWidth);
            FixedPage.SetTop(canvas, capabilities.PageImageableArea.OriginHeight);
            canvas.Width = visibleSize.Width;
            canvas.Height = visibleSize.Height;
            canvas.Background = vb;
            page.Children.Add(canvas);
            yOffset += visibleSize.Height;
        }
        return fixedDoc;
    }

    public static void ShowPrintPreview(FixedDocument fixedDoc)
    {
        var wnd = new Window();
        var viewer = new DocumentViewer();
        viewer.Document = fixedDoc;
        wnd.Content = viewer;
        wnd.ShowDialog();
    }

    public static void PrintNoPreview(PrintDialog printDialog,FixedDocument fixedDoc)
    {
        printDialog.PrintDocument(fixedDoc.DocumentPaginator, "Test Print No Preview");

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, it safes my day. I tried all other things but ignored the PrintVisual method.

Answer (score 1):

You are using PrintDialog.PrintVisual which is only supposed to print what you can see.  For multi-page results you would need to do more.

You could try the  DocumentPaginator http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.documentpaginator.aspx

or

PrintDialog.PrintDocument http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.printdialog.printdocument.aspx.

Comment: when I print visual and select the Microsoft XPS Document Writer it prints fine, I don't think the problem is that I can't see the visual, as I can see all of the visual on screen, the printer seems to cut the paper before it prints all of it.

Answer (score 1):

The last few days i also had this problem.

The solution was to render the root element in memory.

```
PrintDialog dlg = new PrintDialog();

// Let it meassure to the printer's default width
// and use an infinity height
Grid1.Meassure(new Size(dlg.PrintableAreaWidth, double.PositiveInfinity));

// Let it arrange to the meassured size
Grid1.Arrange(new Rect(Grid1.DesiredSize));

// Update the element
Grid1.UpdateLayout();
```

Then create a new papersize for the printer to use:

You should check your printer's cut settings (e.g use `Receipt` cutting mode).

```
// Create a new papersize with the printer's default width, and the Grids height
dlg.PrintTicket.PageMediaSize 
= new PageMediaSize(dlg.PrintableAreaWidth, Grid1.ActualHeight);

// Let's print !
dlg.PrintVisual(Grid1, "blah");
```

This works like a charm for me, and saved me lots of code.

As receipt printer's don't need `pagination`, I think this is very easy to use.

*Note that I **NOT** use this method for rendering an `UIElement` created in XAML, it's all made in code with a `StackPanel` as root element*.

Comment: I was actually printing a visual (so I don't think I can accept this one as answer)?

Comment: Isn't that the same? Btw you don't have to, it's just for future reference if someone else comes across this problem, because I think it's the easiest way to print if you don't need `pagination` ;)

Comment: It probably is just the same, but since the other one works, we probably won't bother testing it, and it also paginates too (in case user does decide to print to A4 printer - I know that wasn't in the original question but seems a good side effect to the answer I accepted).

Comment: I tried this with a visual and it didn't work as wanted. it cuts before finishing. The accepted answer worked (the width was little bit off)